# String operation on a column SAS

Tags: string, sas

I have a column "variable" in a table. This column is basically filed with string like given below. Now I want to break these strings and create a column based on the "delimiter" which is "space".

```
Rejct  2.00  Accept  4.00

Reject 3.00  Accept  9.00

Reject -4.00 Accept -6.00
```

Now If I want to create variables like **Reject** and **Accept** then how to go about it.

```
Reject  Accept

2.00    4.00

3.00    9.00

-4.00  -6.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infile Magic to the rescue.

```
data have;
infile datalines truncover;
input @1 string $30.;
datalines;
Reject 2.00  Accept  4.00
Reject 3.00  Accept  9.00
Reject -4.00 Accept -6.00
;;;;
run;

filename a temp;
data _null_;
file a;
put "1";
run;

data want;
set have;
infile a truncover;
input @1 @@;
_infile_=string;
input
@"Reject" reject BEST5.
@"Accept" accept BEST5.
@@
;
datalines;
run;
```

Basically, you create a dummy file; then you use the power of input @"string" to search for your data.

You could use SUBSTR and/or SCAN to do this, as well.  IE:

```
data want;
set have;
reject = input(scan(string,2,' '),best.);
accept = input(scan(String,4,' '),best.);
run;
```

However, infile magic with @"string" is more flexible if the positions aren't fixed.

Comment: Thanks Joe for such a great answer.